# How to solve $\frac{1}{(|x| - 3)}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$\frac{1}{(|x| - 3)}$  $\lt$  $\frac{1}{2}$

$x$ can be $\ge$ 0 or $\le$ 0

Case 1 :- $x$ $\ge$ 0

$therefore$, $\frac{1}{(x - 3)}$  $\lt$  $\frac{1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{(x - 3)}$ - $\frac{1}{2}$  $\lt$ 0

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{2 - (x - 3)}{{(x - 3)}2}$  $\lt$ 0

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{(2 - x + 3)}{{(x - 3)}}$  $\lt$ 0

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{(5 - x)}{{(x - 3)}}$  $\lt$ 0

$Now$ $if$ $(5-x)$  $\lt$ 0 ,
$then$ $(x - 3)$ $\gt$ 0

$therefore,$ 5 $\lt$ $x$ And x $\gt$ 3

$That$ $is$ $(5, \infty)$

$if$  $(5-x)$  $\gt$ 0  $then$ $(x - 3)$ $\lt$ 0

$therefore$ 5 $\gt$ x $And$ 3 $\gt$ x

$That$ $is$ $(-\infty,3)$

But $x$ $\ge$ 0

$therefore$ $[0,3)$

**therefore, The values of for which the inequality in Case 1 is true are**

$[0,3)$ $\cup$ $(5, \infty)$  $\cdots$ - $(1)$

Case 2:- $x$ $\le$ 0

$therefore$, $\frac{1}{(-x - 3)}$  $\lt$  $\frac{1}{2}$

**As proceed in Case 1, The The values of for which the inequality in Case 2 is true are** 
$(-3,0]$ $\cup$ $(-\infty, -5)$ $\cdots$ - $(2)$

By combining (1) and (2)

We get,

$(-\infty, -5)$ $\cup$  $(-3,3)$ $\cup$ $(5, \infty)$

**therefore the answer for the above inequality is** $(-\infty, -5)$ $\cup$  $(-3,3)$ $\cup$ $(5, \infty)$.

Please tell if this is a good way to do this or even the correct way of doing it ?
Please mention the better of way of doing this, if possible.

Sorry for bad formatting and bad English.

Thank you.

Comment: this is correct, that is the method i would use for such a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\frac{1}{|x|-3}-\frac12=\frac{5-|x|}{2\left(|x|-3\right)},$$ we need to solve $$|x|>5$$ and $$|x|<3.$$ This gives your answer too, but simpler.

Comment: Thanks for help. I posted a question before but nobody answered. Thanks again.

Comment: This questions are easy in general, so people generally don't want to answer this kinda questions. I was free on that time. Since I saw your effort,  I wanted to answer it. It is nice work, continue like this.

Answer (score 0):

To solve $$\frac{1}{(|x| - 3)}  \lt  \frac{1}{2} $$ we want to multiply this by $$2(|x| - 3)$$

Case 1:

$$2(|x| - 3) \gt 0$$ or equivalently $$|x| \gt 3$$
So we multiply the equation an get
$$2 \lt |x| - 3$$
and by adding $3$ to the equation we get
$$ 5 \lt |x|$$  or equivalently $$ |x| \gt 5$$

So we have
$$|x| \gt 3$$
$$ |x| \gt 5$$
which gives
$$ |x| \gt 5$$
This means 
$$(x \gt 5) \lor  (x \lt -5)$$

Case 2:
 $$2(|x| - 3) \lt 0$$, or equivalently $$|x| \lt 3$$
Again we multiply the equation an get
$$2 \gt |x| - 3$$
and by adding $3$ to the equation we get
$$ 5 \gt |x|$$  or equivalently $$ |x| \lt 5$$

Here we have
$$|x| \lt 3$$
$$ |x| \lt 5$$
which gives
$$ |x| \gt 3$$
This means 
$$(x \gt -3) \land  (x \lt 3)$$